# Parametrisable mongoDB collection

Tags: typescript, mongodb

I was wondering if there was a compact way to make calls to different collections depending on a parameter of a function.
Just want to know if it is possible, else I'll do it case by case.

This is the code I have for the moment, and the idea would be to **have a single `create` for the three collections**, as I started.
The thing is, TS tells me "This expression is not callable.
Each member of the union type 'my 3 types' has signatures, but none of those signatures are compatible with each other." on `insertOne` (`this[collection]` works fine)

```
import { Collection, Db, InsertOneResult, ObjectId } from "mongodb";

export type L1CategoryDocument = L1Category & {
    _id: ObjectId;
};

export type L2CategoryDocument = L2Category & {
    _id: ObjectId;
};

export type L3CategoryDocument = L3Category & {
    _id: ObjectId;
};

export class CategoryClient {
    private l1: Collection<L1CategoryDocument>;

    private l2: Collection<L2CategoryDocument>;

    private l3: Collection<L3CategoryDocument>;

    constructor(db: Db) {
        this.l1 = db.collection("l1");
        this.l2 = db.collection("l2");
        this.l3 = db.collection("l3");
    }

    async create(collection: "l1", category: L1Category): Promise<InsertOneResult>;
    async create(collection: "l2", category: L2Category): Promise<InsertOneResult>;
    async create(collection: "l3", category: L3Category): Promise<InsertOneResult>;
    async create(
        collection: "l1" | "l2" | "l3",
        category: L1Category | L2Category | L3Category,
    ): Promise<InsertOneResult> {
        return this[collection].insertOne(category);
    }
}
```

Comment: If the content of the 3 collections are going to be similar and often being queried together, it is recommended to put them in same collection for easier management. You can add a field to indicate the category; and furthermore indexing it / sharding on it to improve performance

Comment: That's not the case here, l3 is a children of l2, so l2 has some more fields linked to l3s, and same for l1 and l2, but else that would be indeed a good turnaround!

Comment: Not sure what that means, but usually [$graphLookup](https://mongoplayground.net/p/IY2FeWq7JbS) would be the recommended way to deal with a recursive / hierarchical structure in MongoDB

Comment: Oh never heard of that, thank you! You exactly got the idea, except that we rather put `parent` in l2 and l3 than `children` in l1 and l2.
But the queries might quickly get heavy, so I'll try and see if I continue with that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, it is recommended to put similar documents(in terms of document content and structure) in the same collection for easier queries and management. For your case, your hierarchical structure can be organized in 1 collection with a field to indicate the category. You can use `$graphLookup` to traverse the tree and fetch documents.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      level: "L1"
    }
  },
  {
    "$graphLookup": {
      "from": "collection",
      "startWith": "$_id",
      "connectFromField": "_id",
      "connectToField": "parent",
      "as": "children"
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/wkk72WFqBxt)